# Is there a way to mimic R's higher order (binary) function shorthand syntax within spark or pyspark?

Tags: r, apache-spark, pyspark

In `R`, I can write the following:

```r
## Explicit
Reduce(function(x,y) x*y, c(1, 2, 3))
# returns 6
```

However, I can also do this less explicitly with the following:

```r
## Less explicit
Reduce(`*`, c(1, 2, 3))
# also returns 6
```

---

In `pyspark`, I could do the following:

```py
rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3])
rdd.reduce(lambda a, b: a * b)
```

---

**Question: Can you mimic the "shorthand" (less explicit) syntax of R's `Reduce('*', ...)` with `pyspark` or some sort of anonymous function?**

Comment: If you're more at home with R, you should check out SparkR, it's included in Spark 1.4.0. (I haven't tried it yet.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In R, you're supplying a binary function. The multiply operator (as with all operators) is actually a binary function. Type

```
`*`(2, 3)
```

to see what I mean.

In Python, the equivalent for multiplication is `operator.mul`.

So:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3])
rdd.reduce(operator.mul)
```